# Can't run sudo apt-get install <anything>

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am getting the following error on my terminal

E: The package libllvm3.8 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

when I try to run apt-get install or apt-get upgrade. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: run `sudo apt install -f` then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Answer (score 2):

run `sudo apt install -f` then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

From man page: Configure a package which has been unpacked but not yet  configured. If  -a  or  --pending  is  given instead of package, all unpacked but unconfigured packages are configured.

from man page : -f, --fix-broken
Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.
This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages
to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. If packages are
specified, these have to completely correct the problem. The option
is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT
itself does not allow broken package dependencies to exist on a
system. It is possible that a system's dependency structure can be
so corrupt as to require manual intervention (which usually means
using dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the offending packages).
Use of this option together with -m may produce an error in some
situations. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Fix-Broken.

Comment: I tried this. It is not working. Something about the package status being half installed is showing up

Comment: try `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq --dry-run libllvm3.8` if that's the package in question